# Aapt error -1073741816

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, adt

I seem to be getting this error a lot.

```
Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741816   RTZone      line 1  Android ADT Problem
```

I tried this with a lot of configurations (Different JDKs, x86, x64, ADT versions etc)

Currently running Windows 8 Pro x64, Intel Core i7 3610QM, NVidia Gefore GTX 660M, 16GB RAM.

What I get from the verbose build in console might help.

```
[2013-04-08 19:39:57 - RTZone]     (new resource id abs__screen_action_bar from                D:\Projects\Android\ActionBarSherlock\res\layout-xlarge\abs__screen_action_bar.xml)
[2013-04-08 19:39:57 - RTZone]     (new resource id abs__screen_action_bar_overlay from D:\Projects\Android\ActionBarSherlock\res\layout\abs__screen_action_bar_overlay.xml)
[2013-04-08 19:39:57 - RTZone]     (new resource id abs__screen_action_bar_overlay from D:\Projects\Android\ActionBarSherlock\res\layout-xlarge\abs__screen_action_bar_overlay.xml)
[2013-04-08 19:39:57 - RTZone]     (new resource id abs__screen_simple from D:\Projects\Android\ActionBarSherlock\res\layout\abs__screen_simple.xml)
[2013-04-08 19:39:57 - RTZone]     (new resource id abs__screen_simple_overlay_action_mode from D:\Projects\Android\ActionBarSherlock\res\layout\abs__screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml)
[2013-04-08 19:39:57 - RTZone]     (new resource id abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line from D:\Projects\Android\ActionBarSherlock\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml)
[2013-04-08 19:40:00 - RTZone]     (new reso
[2013-04-08 19:40:00 - RTZone] 'aapt' error. Pre Compiler Build aborted.
```

Might it be not enough memory problem or something? I tried boosting up the Eclipse limit but that didn't help :/

Comment: Those links are incredibly slow for me, could you copy/paste the text in here instead? You can format it as code for easy readability.

Comment: Edited replaced the links :)

Comment: @marcindobry, could you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61308. It a crash in the AAPT tool where it fails to generate proper error messages on certain kinds of errors in the resource files.

You can find advice on what to fix in the bug report, but in short, it's generally caused by a reference to a missing reference in one of your resource files. An invalid @string reference in a menu resource seems a common culprit, for example:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/non_existent_string_resource"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
```